# Does Changing F-stop Affect Render Time?

Tags: rendering, camera, eevee-render-engine

I am rendering an animation. It is taking a lot of time even though it is being rendered in EEVEE. I think is that it is because of the f-stop value being too low.

My question is, does the f-stop value affect the render time dramatically or should I take into account other things as well?

Comment: Hello :). Yes, lower f-stop values cause more of your scene to be out of focus, which can lead to longer render times.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would also like to know how much impact does it have? Like can it increase the time by a 100 times?

Comment: Hey :). The impact is rather small, at most a few percent for complex scenes. I don't think it's worth to worry about it too much :).

Comment: Have you rendered without depth of field for a qucik check if it gets a 100 times faster? This would be the easiest way to find out if there are other things than the f-stop slowing down your render...

Comment: Yes for frames with high f-stop value the render time was around 2 seconds. But where the f stop value was low like 20-30 the render time for each frame was around 2 minutes. I think it was the f-stop value increasing the render time. I couldnt find any other factor